# Can self-supervised pretraining work with only labeled data?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, self-supervised-learning

I am working on an image classification problem with only a few samples (10 images). As part of the challenge, we aren't allowed to use any external data or pretrained models. I was wondering whether the self-supervised learning techniques that are normally done on unlabelled data would work if I only used them on just the 10 labeled images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-supervised learning is effective because it allows researchers to use much more data than they would have time/money to label. If you can't expand your training dataset using self-supervised learning, you may as well stick with supervised learning.

Comment: Fair enough. Can you guide me towards any other approaches I can explore?

Comment: You could use data augmentation (https://towardsai.net/p/l/an-introduction-to-data-augmentation-for-images-using-tensorflows-imagedatagenerator) to add some additional variability to your training set, but even this won't do much to prevent overfitting in such a small sample.

Comment: Already doing that. What about ensemble methods? I never see them in the context of neural networks but do you think it's worth a shot?

Comment: To use ensemble methods, you would first have to find another machine learn technique that would work well on images. 

Is there a feature you could manually extract from the image? If, for example, you're trying to distinguish vertical bars from horizontal bars, you may be able to define a function that extracts that feature without worrying about overfitting.

My only other thought is that if your images were large enough, you could break each image into 10 smaller tiles, label the sub-tiles, and train the model to predict those sub-labels.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of training multiple models with the same architecture (or with slight changes) independently. Breaking up images seems like a good idea but the images are pretty small unfortunately.